# How to setup swagger-springmvc 0.6.5 with a Spring 3.1.2 application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to use swagger-springmvc 0.6.6 in a Spring 3.1.2 project. But when I deploy the application to Tomcat it's failing with an exception.

There seems to be a problem with versions I am using. swagger-springmvc also brings in Spring 3.2.4 jars which are conflicting with Spring 3.1.2 jars.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean
'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2'
while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [2]; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2
.......

....nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean
```

The `org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean` class is found in both Spring 3.1.2 and Spring 3.2.4.

When I try to run the app in my Local smachine its running without issues.

Could someone help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: You probably should specify what tool you are using to build your project: Maven? Eclipse? something else? You can also have a look inside your `WAR` (in `WEB-INF/lib`) to see which libraries are packaged there. Are there actually two versions of any Spring jar?

Comment: Alexey-Thanks for the response . I am building the WAR with Ant .depoying in tomcat.Yes there are two versions of Spring . spring 3.1.2(application using) and spring 3.2.4(swagger-spingMvc using).When i deploy the application locally in my eclipse configured tomcat the application is working without any issues.

Comment: @alexey  -Thanks for the response . I am building the WAR with Ant .depoying in tomcat.Yes there are two versions of Spring . spring 3.1.2(application using) and spring 3.2.4(swagger-spingMvc using).When i deploy the application locally in my eclipse configured tomcat the application is working without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this sample configuration. It is a very plain vanilla setup which shows the bare minimum configuration required.

JDK 6
Tomcat 7
Spring 3.2.4

https://github.com/varoonverma/Swagger.git

Cheers,